# Workaround ['no permission'] error using Python urllib2, requests or pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, urllib2, backend

I'm trying to load a csv using urllib2 (In this example I use urllib2 but the exact same error happens when I use pandas or requests) but whenever I try to read it, I get a ['no permission'] error:

import csv
import urllib2

```
url = 'https://...'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
cr = csv.reader(response)

for row in cr:
    print row
```

I alredy use exactly the same method to download other csv's from distinct sources, and this one is the only one posing a problem. The source is an external backend which might have rules against scraping of some sort, because when I use the url manually from my browser the .csv download works fine.

The following is the response.**dict** output which also looks fine:

```
>>> response.__dict__

     {'fp': <socket._fileobject object at 0x7f066c6c1ad0>, 'fileno': <bound method _fileobject.fileno of <socket._fileobject object at
 0x7f066c6c1ad0>>, 'code': 200, 'read': <bound method _fileobject.read
 of <socket._fileobject object at 0x7f066c6c1ad0>>, 'readlines': <bound
 method _fileobject.readlines of <socket._fileobject object at
 0x7f066c6c1ad0>>, 'next': <bound method _fileobject.next of
 <socket._fileobject object at 0x7f066c6c1ad0>>, 'headers':
 <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x7f066a0b9758>, '__iter__': <bound
 method _fileobject.__iter__ of <socket._fileobject object at
 0x7f066c6c1ad0>>, 'url':
 'https://....',
 'msg': 'OK', 'readline': <bound method _fileobject.readline of
 <socket._fileobject object at 0x7f066c6c1ad0>>}
```

**EDIT:**

the url already includes a user validation which is static in this case:

```
url = 'https://www.xxx.cm/admin/index.php?
editlanguage=1
&stoken=yyy
&cl=cvvcontrolpanel
&fnc=downloadExportFile
&csv_profile_id=20'
```

My token is always the same and the download works fine when trying the url from my browser even after closing session.

Comment: Could you show output (stacktrace) for your code?

Comment: I feel like the source provides some kind of auth and it's failed for vanilla urllib2.

Comment: The problem is that I can't check for any errors since the download appears to be ok